# How can I properly create a unit test to test the functionality of cases in a switch statement in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I could use some help on an issue I am stuck with. I am trying to create a unit test that the functionality of cases in a switch statement. However, the code given for the assignment passes a view as a parameter in the method and I have to use the id as the label for the case. No other parameters are passed in via the method so I am sort of stuck. I assume I will have to generate my own variables and use them to calculate, but I am new to this and hitting a wall on how to do this.

A friendly nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
public void btnOnClick(View v) {

    float num1 = 0;
    float num2 = 0;
    float result = 0;

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnAdd:
        oper = "+";
        result = num2 + num2;
        break;
    case R.id.btnSub:
        oper = "-";
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case R.id.btnMult:
        oper = "*";
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case R.id.btnDiv:
        oper = "/";
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

WIP TEST CODE

```
@Test
public void btnOnClickTest() {

    // Do I need to use my own variables???
    float num1 = 5;
    float num2 = 5;
    float result;

    //generating an instance of the activity to use
    MainActivity calc = new MainActivity();

    // Not sure how to structure this part
    assertTrue(calc.buttononClick(R.id.btnAdd));
    assertTrue(calc.buttononClick(R.id.btnSub));
    assertTrue(calc.buttononClick(R.id.btnMult));
    assertTrue(calc.buttononClick(R.id.btnDiv));

}
```

Comment: You have a variable that you do not use later - `result`. Also, what is `oper`? If it's a field in the class, then you change whether this field has changed

Comment: It is probably easiest for you to _mock_ the `View` object you pass to the method. An example using Mockito is [in the tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html). You only need to mock the view to provide the value of your choice for `getId()`.

Comment: @RoyalBg the oper is used later in a printout so it is not relevant to the test.

Comment: @MickMnemonic thanks I will review the link. I do see that I need to add this since testComplie is no longer in use.